# Prevent Sleep on Mac OS

Tags: macos, cocoa, sleep, launchd

my application doesn't seem to be able to prevent system sleep on Mac OS Mountain Lion.

*Here is what it should do:*

A Cocoa application gets launched at a certain time using the launchd process. Preventing system sleep is done at launch of the application using IOPMAssertionCreateWithName. The application simply has a (hidden) WebView, calls several URLs, parses the content, sends results to a webserver, quits.

*Here is my code to prevent sleep:*

```
- (void)preventSleep
{
    CFStringRef reasonForActivity= CFSTR("Content parsing");

    IOReturn success = IOPMAssertionCreateWithName(kIOPMAssertionTypeNoDisplaySleep,
                                                   kIOPMAssertionLevelOn, reasonForActivity, &self.assertionID);
    if (success == kIOReturnSuccess)
    {
        Log([NSColor orangeColor], @"Prevent sleep\n");
    }
}
```

*This is what is going on:*

The launchd process works fine. The sleeping system wakes up, the application starts, prints "Prevent sleep" in my log, parses some URLs, but suddenly after a few seconds the system wents to sleep.

*What is happening?*

Is IOPMAssertionCreateWithName maybe not working with applications launched by launchd on a system with no user activity?

What can i do to prevent the system from sleeping while my application is processing?

Answer (score 0):

OS X 10.7 will return to sleep, if no user activity is detected. You can simulate user activity using the following function:

```
UpdateSystemActivity(OverallAct);
```

Please, note that this will turn the screen on.

Comment: I am using 10.9. UpdateSystemActivity is deprecated since 10.8. Replaced by IOPMAssertionCreateWithName.

Is it still functional? Since it's a private project i am trying it out at least.

Comment: I can confirm that it is still functional on 10.9. As long as there are people out there that use Snow Leopard, Apple will not be able to put this function out of their libraries!

Comment: Guess you're right. Now I am using both IOPMAssertionCreateWithName and UpdateSystemActivity. However, the system is still going to sleep for some reason. 

Every morning I wake up the mac, check the log and its continuing parsing. Any ideas?

Comment: Another thing you might try is to get notified when the system is going to sleep. This way, your app will get 30 more seconds to do its stuff.

You have to try this one, anyway. I'm assuming that the NSWorkspaceWillSleepNotification is posted even though the system is going to sleep without any user interaction.